# How to get ImageData from image in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image

I am trying to get the [ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) in nodejs, the *images* may come from any source, to get ImageData canvas can be used, but canvas is not available in backend, in one of the question asked here I found [canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas) for nodejs, but it requires additional installations in the system.

is there any easy way, like reading *image* using node `fs` module and giving output in ImageData format, so that it can be used for further processing.

Comment: `The ImageData interface represents the underlying pixel data of an area of a <canvas> element.` - node doesn't do canvas, so you're using the wrong tool for the job ... the right tool depends on where/how you get the image ... `may come from any source` doesn't help explain where you get this image from

Comment: you want the "binary" of the image?